# Populate text box when checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, text, checkbox

I have a form with a Website text field and multiple (5-6) checkboxes. I need specific text to be populated into the Website field based on which checkbox has been selected.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfkjP.jpg)

Comment: You could have dataset attributes with the values you wish to populate into the textContent or value section of your display element. Then you use the e.targets dataset attribute to populate that info. I would add any code to your question that you have tried so far.

Comment: I am a beginner using java script in PDF documents/forms. I have scoured the internet and tried so many. I think I am in over my head. You really can't teach an old dog new tricks, hahaha.

Answer (score 1):

Well, my husband figured out how to accomplish this task.

1. Target text box is read only.
2. Using the 'calculate' tab, choose custom calculation script and add the following:

   ```
   event.value = "";
   if (this.getField("Division").value == "Yes") {
       event.value = this.getField("Website").value;
       event.value = "website address"}
       if (this.getField("Division").value == "Choice2") {
           event.value = this.getField("Website").value;event.value = "website"
       }
       if (this.getField("Division").value == "Choice3") {
           event.value = this.getField("Website").value;event.value = "website"
       }
       if (this.getField("Division").value == "Choice4") {
           event.value = this.getField("Website").value;event.value = "website"
       }
       if (this.getField("Division").value == "Choice5") {
           event.value = this.getField("Website").value;event.value = "website"
       }
       if (this.getField("Division").value == "Choice6") {
           event.value = this.getField("Website").value;event.value = "website"
       }
   ```
3. Replace "choice" with your checkbox name and "website address" with the desired information for the text field.

Hope this is helpful for anyone else who may need this task.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do it with an event listener, getting the name of the checkbox input and inject it into your website input.

Here is an example with just one checkbox

```js
const mc_checkbox = document.getElementById("checkbox_mc");

mc_checkbox.addEventListener("click", function () {
  if(mc_checkbox.checked){
    document.getElementById("input_website").value = mc_checkbox.name;
  }
  else{
    document.getElementById("input_website").value = '';
  }
});
```

```html
<div>
  <label>Website</label>
  <input type="text"id="input_website" />
</div>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_mc" name="MC" />
  <label>MC</label>
</div>
```